# Select all posts created this current week with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## posts_controller.rb

```
def index
  @current_week = Post.where(:created_at => (Date.today - 7)..(Date.today))                      
end
```

## views/index.html.erb

```
@current_week.each do |post|
  ....
end
```

Rails return an empty array.
I just want to select all the video created the current week.
Do you see where I'm wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: You mean in the last 7 days or do you literally mean in the current week?

Comment: Your code is not wrong. Please check your database. No posts have been created in the last 7 days.

Comment: I mean in the current week. The solution provided by RSB is working :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `at_beginning_of_week` to fetch records created in the current week

```
@current_week = Post.where("created_at >= ?", Date.today.at_beginning_of_week)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works :)
If I want to get only the posts for the last week, (not the current week, one week before) do you know if there is a method ?

Comment: Sure, in that case you can do `Date.today.at_beginning_of_week - 7`